# How can I ask for n and type the n numbers in only one line

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

The usual way to input n numbers is to first ask for n and then type n numbers in different lines.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
```

How can I ask for n and type the n numbers in only one line.

Something like this:

```
>> 4 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I ask for n and type the n numbers in only one line.

You don't *need* to ask for *n* if it's obvious from the whitespace-separated input how many integers you have.

However, if the input string format is non-negotiable, you can split via sequence unpacking:

```
n, *num_list = map(int, input().split())
```

For example, with input `'4 1 2 3 4'`, you will have the following result:

```
print(n, num_list)

4 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To understand the above logic:

1. `input().split()` splits a string input by whitespace into a list.
2. `map(int, X)` returns an **iterable** of `int` applied to each element in `X`.
3. `n, *num_list = map(...)` iterates the `map` object and separates into the first and the rest.

---

More idiomatic would be to calculate `n` yourself:

```
num_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
n = len(num_list)
```

For example, with input `'1 2 3 4'`, you will have the following result:

```
print(n, num_list)

4 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

The only purpose of entering the number of numbers explicitly is to provide a check. This is possible via an `assert` statement:

```
n, *num_list = map(int, input().split())

assert n == len(num_list), f'Check failed: {n} vs {len(num_list)} provided does not match'
```

Comment: What does this `map(int, input().split())` do?

Comment: Note for OP that an equally valid result would be `4 1 2 3 4 5`. The first number does not validate the rest (you'll have to implement that logic yourself)

Comment: @AdamSmith, Agreed, I've added the only *possible* use I can see of having the initial count, some kind of explicit check on the subsequent input.

Comment: @jpp wait does that work? I had no idea you could hand `assert` a tuple with an error message attached. Man, I've been writing Python for a decade or more and am still learning core language features. Feelsbadman

Comment: @AdamSmith, Formatted string literals (f-strings) were only introduced in Python 3.6, see [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). But otherwise, I think the `assert` syntax is standard in Python3.

Comment: @jpp yup, f-strings are (still the coolest thing since sliced bread, but...) old news. It was the `assert predicate, errormsg` syntax I was just now learning about.

Answer (score 0):

```
space_separated_numbers = input()
num_list = [int(x) for x in space_separated_numbers.split()]
```

The trick is to take the whole input as a string at once, and then split it yourself.

EDIT: If you are only concerned with getting the first number, just get the first value instead.

```
space_separated_numbers = input()
num = space_separated_numbers.split()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it just adds all numbers into a list.

Comment: what would you like it to do instead? @Miguel

Comment: Hmmm. I would only need to pop the front element.

Comment: Updated @Miguel , though i think you have all choices as you see fit once you get them all in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try processing the entire input as a string. Then convert them to integers. In that case, you won't need to specify the value of n too.

```
>>> x = [int(y) for y in input().split()]
1 2 3 4
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can then work with the values by iterating through the list. If you need the value of n, just get the length of the list.

```
>>> n = len(x)
>>> n
4
```